# c# to vb.net SequenceEqual error

Tags: vb.net

I am encountering an error while converting a c# script to vb.net.

The c# code goes like this:

> if (managed.ComputeHash(destinationArray).SequenceEqual(secondArray))

Using code conversion tool, I got this error in vb.net, please see image:

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkYbQ.png)

http://s2.postimg.org/ouxqvhubd/calc_error.png

I am a newbie in this so please help me how can I solve this error.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please do not post errors as images.  Some people cannot see them because they are blocked.  Please edit your post and include the text of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you,

```
If managed.ComputeHash(destinationArray).SequenceEqual(secondArray) Then
```

However as you only provided a short section it's difficult to relate it to anything else.

Comment: `If managed.ComputeHash(destinationArray).SequenceEqual(secondArray) Then` is the same code as OP posted minus the outer parentheses......